# Is there a standard term for this graph/set theoretic concept?

Tags: graph-theory, gn.general-topology, terminology

For a fixed set $X$ and a finite collection $E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_k\subseteq X$, define the binary relation *adjacency* as follows: $E_i,E_j$ are adjacent
if their intersection is nonempty.
We term the transitive closure of this relation by
*transitive adjacency*
and define the *adjacent union* by
$$
\tilde\cup(E_1,\ldots,E_k):=
\begin{cases}
  \bigcup_{i=1}^k E_i, & \text{the $(E_i)$ are transitively adjacent}
  \\
  \emptyset, & \text{else}
.  
\end{cases}
$$

Are there standard terms for *transitive adjacency* and *adjacent union*?

Comment: As you define it, adjacency is not an equivalence relation, since it is not transitive. And if you apply the transitive closure, then every two non-empty sets $A$ and $B$ become equivalent, because $A$ is adjacent to $A \cup B$, and $A \cup B$ is adjacent to $B$...

Comment: Good points, will edit!

Comment: I see. A collection of subsets is sometimes called a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph), but I don't know if there are already terms for what you are defining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think in terms of [intersection graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_graph). The transitive adjacency tells you when two vertices are adjacent. The adjacency union is then empty if and only if two of $E_1,\ldots,E_k$ are in distinct connected components.

Comment: Thanks! Since asking the question, it's looking like I won't be needing this concept after all -- at least not for now :)

Comment: I guess transitive adjacency tells you when two vertices are in the same connected component.

Comment: Exactly. That's another way of stating it.

Comment: But adjacent means connected by 1 edge of the graph, right?

Comment: In the traditional graph interpretation, yes.

Comment: So... transitive adjacency does not tell you when two vertices are adjacent.

Comment: No, because when you take the transitive closure of the adjacency relation you get a reachability relation or, as you said, a relation that tells you whether two vertices belong to the same connected component.

Answer (score 5):

In philosophy, this would be called [family resemblance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_resemblance) -- if $E_i\cap E_j\ne\emptyset$ and $E_j\cap E_k\ne\emptyset$ then $E_i$ and $E_k$ have a family resemblance.

That is, perhaps I have no common feature with my second cousin, but we both have common features with our common great-grandparent. Similarly, there may be no single thing that is common to all "games".

The idea that every-day concepts such as *game* and *number* exhibit family resemblance comes from Wittgenstein's notes from 1930, so perhaps it is prior to the notion of **intersection graphs** as in @ViniciusdosSantos' answer, which seems to only go back to 1945.